# how to solve this implode(): Invalid arguments passed in

Tags: php, mysql

```
function getAddTrainingProvider($pretraining_provider_name,$courses,$url,$email,$phone,$login_user_id,$usertypeid,$status){ 

$responsess = json_decode($courses); 
$course_ids[] = implode(",",$responsess); 
$query= "INSERT INTO sz_pretraining_provider (pretraining_provider_name,pretraining_provider_course,pretraining_provider_url,pretraining_provider_email,pretraining_provider_phone,login_user_id,usertypeid,status) VALUES ('".$pretraining_provider_name."','".$course_ids."','".$url."','".$email."','".$phone."','".$login_user_id."','".$usertypeid."','".$status."')";
    $result         = mysqli_query($this->mysqli,$query);
    $id             = mysqli_insert_id($this->mysqli);
    return $id;
}
```

how to get array values from implode()

Comment: implode doesn't give array it  takes array as input and a delimiter and returns string

Comment: implode return a string by passing an array and a delemeter

Comment: ok i'm using implode() to get this values (["182","183","192"]) - Array ( [0] => 182,183,192 ). how to store this array values in database table please give mysql code format

Comment: You can not directly stores data in array format into database. For that you need to convert it into string or in json format.

Comment: Array ( [0] => 182 [1] => 183 [2] => 192 ) how can i store this array values to database using mysql in php